# Stieltjes integral in Riesz representation theorem

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, continuity

Let $ X = C[0,1]  $ and let  $ X^* = (C[0,1])^* $ denote conjugated space and $ f \in X^* $. Riesz representation theorem says that there exists $ v \in BV[0,1]$ such that for every $ x \in X$:

$$ f(x) = \int_0^1 x(t) dv(t) \text{.}  $$

Consider the following example. Let $f(x) = \int_{1/2}^{2/3} x(t) dt $ and we have to find $v \in BV[0,1] $. I guess that $ v(t) = t$ for $ t \in [1/2, 2/3) $ and $0 $ otherwise is such function ($v$ have to be right-continuous).

Now take arbitrary $x \in X $. Without loss of generality we can take $x(t) = t $ for $t \in [0,1] $. Then we have:
$$ f(x) = \int_{1/2}^{2/3} t dt = \frac{7}{72} \text{.}  $$

On the other hand we have:
$$ \int_0^1 t dv(t) = \frac{1}{2}(v(\frac{1}{2}) - v(\frac{1}{2}-)) + \int_{1/2}^{2/3} t dt + \frac{2}{3} ( v(\frac{2}{3}) - v (\frac{2}{3}-)) \neq  \frac{7}{72}  \text{.} $$

Is there a general rule to find the $v$ function which is mentioned in Riesz representation theorem? Or I have to guess such function? If my guess is correct I suppose I incorrectly calculate Stieltjes integral. How to deal Stielsjes integral with discontinuous integrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are integrating continuous functions with respect to $v$, the normalization of $v$ is not critical. What is important is the net jump of $v$ at a point. For example, if $v$ is $0$ on $[0,1/2)$, is $1$ on $(1/2,1]$, then the particular value of $v(1/2)$ does not matter in computing $\int_0^1 fdv$ if $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. A standard type of normalization is to require that $v$ is continuous from the right on $[0,1)$. Then $v$ is unique. Likewise, $v$ is unique if you instead require it to be continuous from the left on $(0,1]$.

One way to obtain $v$ "constructively" is to use the Hahn-Banach Theorem to extend $f$ to a $\tilde{f}$ on $L^{\infty}[0,1]$ with $\|f\|=\|\tilde{f}\|$. Then $v(t)=\tilde{f}(\chi_{[0,t]})$ is a function such that $f(x)=\int_0^1 x(t)dv(t)$. The particular $v$ may not be normalized, but you can normalize it to be left- or right-continuous. This Hahn-Banach construction is one of the most intuitive constructions, and it shows you just how powerful the Axiom of Choice can be in cutting this problem down to size.